# How to get out of the brackets using the TAB key in PyDev?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Is there a way to set a `TAB` key as a key used to move cursor outside the quotation marks or the brackets in Eclipses' PyDev plugin? It's default for example in Java perspective, but in PyDev I have to use `right arrow key` in default.

Comment: what do you mean by ' "escaper" of the brackets'?

Comment: A key used to move cursor outside the quotation marks or the brackets.

Comment: I posted some info in the answer, though it may not exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have pydev but I couldn't find a key to jump to the end of the quotation marks. The closest I could see is Ctrl+Shift+P that takes me to the matching bracket. However I thought following may be useful for you:

> 1. Hit **Ctrl+Shift+L** --> This will show you a list of all shortcut keys available
> 2. If you hit **Ctrl+Shift+L** *again* it will take you to a preferences page where you can see what all are available by various categories.
>      You can setup your own binding if you want to change anything.